# K-Means Clustering Method

Tags: r, k-means

[Description of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZBdA.png)
I am trying to produce in `R` a suitable graphical display of the cluster means.

How can I place the attributes on the `x-axis` and treat the `means` for each cluster as trajectories over the items?

All the data is continuous.

Comment: What do you mean trajectories?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, add some data, some code, and a clear mockup of the desired result, to help to be helped.

Comment: I created 4 K-means clusters and now I was trying to find a way to display the cluster means and also show which attributes are used in each cluster. This is just an idea that occurred to me, but I am sure if it is a suitable idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the following approach: since your variables are on a similar measurement scale (e.g. Likert scale) you could show the distribution of each variable within each cluster (with e.g. boxplots) and visually compare their distribution by using the same axis limits on every cluster.

This can be accomplished by a putting your data in a suitable format and using the `ggplot2` package to generate the plot. This is shown below.

#### Step 1: Generate simulated data to mimic the numeric data you have

The generated data contains four non-negative integer variables and a cluster variable with 3 clusters.

```
library(ggplot2)
    
set.seed(1717)    # make the simulated data repeatable
N = 100
nclusters = 3
cluster = as.numeric( cut(rnorm(N), breaks=nclusters, label=seq_len(nclusters)) )
df = data.frame(cluster=cluster,
                x1=floor(cluster + runif(N)*5),
                x2=floor(runif(N)*5),
                x3=floor((nclusters-cluster) + runif(N)*5),
                x4=floor(cluster + runif(N)*5))
df$cluster = factor(df$cluster)  # define cluster as factor to ease plotting code below
tail(df)
table(df$cluster)
```

whose output is:

```
    cluster x1 x2 x3 x4
95        2  5  2  5  2
96        3  5  4  0  3
97        3  3  3  1  7
98        2  5  4  3  3
99        3  6  1  1  7
100       3  5  1  2  5

 1  2  3 
15 64 21
```

i.e., out of the 100 simulated cases, the data contains 15 cases in cluster 1, 64 cases in cluster 2 and 21 cases in cluster 3.

#### Step 2: Prepare the data for plotting

Here we use `reshape()` from the `stats` package to transpose the dataset from wide to long so that the four numeric variables (`x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4`) are placed into *one single column*, suitable for generating a boxplot for each of the four variables which are then grouped by the cluster variable.

```
vars2transpose = c("x1", "x2","x3", "x4")
df.long = reshape(df, direction="long", idvar="id",
                  varying=list(vars2transpose),
                  timevar="var", times=vars2transpose, v.names="value")
head(df.long)
table(df.long$cluster)
```

whose output is:

```
     cluster var value id
1.x1       1  x1     5  1
2.x1       1  x1     3  2
3.x1       3  x1     5  3
4.x1       1  x1     1  4
5.x1       2  x1     3  5
6.x1       1  x1     2  6

  1   2   3 
 60 256  84
```

Note that the number of cases in each cluster has increased 4-fold (i.e. the number of numeric variables) since the data is now in transposed long format.

#### Step 3: Create the variable's boxplots by cluster with line-connected means

We plot horizontal boxplots for each variable `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4` that show their distribution in each cluster, and mark the mean values with connected red crosses (the trajectories you are after).

```
gg <- ggplot(df.long, aes(x=var, y=value))
gg + facet_grid(cluster ~ ., labeller=label_both) +
     geom_boxplot(aes(fill=cluster)) +
     stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point", color="red", pch="x", size=3) +
     stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="line", color="red", aes(group=1)) +
     coord_flip()  # swap the x and y axis to make boxplots horizontal instead of vertical
```

which generates the following graph.
[image: variable distribution by cluster]

The graph might get packed with the many variables you have, so you may want to:

- either show vertical boxplots by removing the last `coord_flip()` line
- or remove the boxplots altogether and just show the connected red crosses by eliminating the `geom_boxplot()` line.

And if you want to compare each variable side by side among the different clusters, you can swap the grouping and x-axis variables as follows:

```
gg <- ggplot(df.long, aes(x=cluster, y=value))
gg + facet_grid(var ~ ., labeller=label_both) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group=cluster, fill=cluster)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point", color="red", pch="x", size=3) +
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="line", color="red", aes(group=1)) +
  coord_flip()  # swap the x and y axis to make boxplots horizontal instead of vertical
```

[image: variable distribution side by side]